# Wie nennt man die Person/Sache, von der jemand/etwas abhängig ist?

Tags: single-word-request

Der/die/das Abhängige ist abhängig vom *Abhängigkeitsgeber*?

Zu weiteren Eingrenzung: Selbst "Substanz" und "Lehnsherr" wären noch zu spezifisch.

Die Idee ist ein sehr allgemeiner Ausdruck, etwa auf dem Niveau, wie in der Subtraktion der "Subtrahend" vom "Minuend" abgezogen wird.

Optional: Falls es sich nicht direkt übersetzen lässt, wäre der entsprechende Ausdruck im Englischen erfreulich. (Ich möchte jetzt keinen Crosspost erstellen.)

Falls es hilft, die Frage entstand in der Informatik, wo eine Klasse von einer anderen abhängig ist, ist aber darüber hinausgewachsen.

**EDIT:**
"Minuend" und "Subtrahend" vertauscht. Konnt ich nicht so stehen lassen.

**Ergänzung:**
Weil es in den Kommentaren diskutiert wird: Die Informatik ist nur der Ursprung, es soll aber eben *keine* Einschränkung sein, eventuell als Ideengeber.

> ist aber darüber hinausgewachsen

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. "entstand in der Informatik" - d.h., Objektorientierung? Da dachte ich heißt es Superklasse. Die Frage geht also nach einem abstrakten Begriff, der im allerweitesten Sinn den "Abhängigkeitsgeber" benennt? Spontan glaube ich, dass das nur Kontextbezogen geht. Und "der entsprechende Ausdruck im Englischen" impliziert, dass es den a) dort gibt und b) keine Übersetzung existiert. Zählt "Sound" als keine Übersetzung oder als Anglizismus?

Comment: Der Subtrahend wird vom Minuend abgezogen.

Comment: So ziemlich die gleiche Frage gabs bereits bei Englisch SE [What is the correct word for “dependee”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25575/what-is-the-correct-word-for-dependee)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Zwar begründet Ableitung eine Abhängigkeit, aber wenn Deine Klasse Auto Räder hat, ist sie auch von Rädern abhängig, ohne von diesen abgeleitet zu sein.

Comment: Ich kenne "Suchtmittel"; das passt bei Glücksspiel vielleicht noch, bei wirtschaftlicher Abhängigkeit oder in der Softwareentwicklung aber sicher nicht. "Abhängigkeitsgeber" ist aber noch schlechter - das passt nirgends. Das "~geben" suggeriert eine Aktivität, die oft nicht gegeben ist. Benutzt wird es m.W. auch nicht.

Comment: Wie sieht es mit dem Begriffspaar *superordinate* - *subordinate* aus? Auf deutsch dann *übergeordnet* und *untergeordnet*.

Comment: @Olafant, natürlich, habs geändert.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Und wer ist dann der Abhängige? Lt. Hegel kann der Herr ohne Knechte nicht Herr sein, sowenig wie die Knechte ohne Herr Knecht. Ohne Erläuterung wird wohl kaum wer bei "das Übergeordnete" an Drogen denken.

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe mich auf das in der Frage genauer eingegrenzte Problem der Abhängigkeit zweier Klassen in der Programmierung bezogen. Von Drogen oder Hegel ist in der Frage nicht die Rede.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Wie interpretierst Du dann "Substanz", welches zu spezifisch sein soll?

Answer (score 2):

In der [Dependenzgrammatik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependenzgrammatik) spricht man vom *Regens*. Das abhängige Element ist das *Dependens* (Plural *Dependentien*).

Ein Sprachwissenschaftler, der diese Begriffe benutzt hat, ist [Ulrich Engel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulrich_Engel_(Philologe)). Online ist z.B. der Artikel "Neues zur DVG" ([Link](https://ids-pub.bsz-bw.de/frontdoor/index/index/year/2018/docId/7260)). Dort heißt es in Abschnitt 2.2 *Regens und Dependens*:

> Dependentielle Beschreibungen beruhen immer auf Abhängigkeits-Hierarchien: Jedes Element (d.h. jeder Knoten im Diagramm) ist regierendes Element (= Regens) oder abhängiges Element (= Dependens) und oft beides zugleich. Generell gilt in der Dependenzgrammatik, dass es nur Verzweigungen nach unten gibt. Anders: Jedes Element kann nur ein Regens haben; jedes Element kann mehrere Dependentien haben. Welches Element in einer Zweierstruktur als Regens, welches als Dependens fungiert, ist nicht vorgegeben, sondern muss im Einzelfall entschieden werden. So steht nicht von vornherein fest, ob das Determinativ das Nomen regiert oder umgekehrt, ob das Modalverb das Hauptverb regiert oder umgekehrt usw. Tesnière, der ursprünglich Lehrer war, hat solche Fragen weitgehend auf Grund pädagogischer Erfahrungen beantwortet, das Problem aber nie thematisiert.

Comment: Mir gefällt das. Ist es vertretbar, das in andere Kontexte (z.B. die Informatik) zu übernehmen? Z.B.: "Regens finanzieller Abhängigkeiten sind für gewöhnlich die Eltern und der Arbeitgeber, bei Substanzabhängigkeiten sind es Alkohol und Nikotin. In der Informatik ist das Vorhandensein des Regens einer Abhängigkeit Vorraussetzung zur Kompilierung". (Inhaltliche Richtigkeit sei dahingestellt.)

Comment: @Sebastian Prinzipiell finde ich es sinnvoll, wenn nicht immer neue Begriffe erfunden, sondern auch gelegentlich welche aus anderen Disziplinen entlehnt werden. Allerdings nur, wenn die Entlehnung sinnvoll ist, und die gewählten Beispiele lassen mich daran zweifeln. Bei den Softwarepaketen paßt der Abhängigkeitsbegriff der Dependenzgrammatik (DG) nicht, da in der Regel ein Paket von mehreren anderen Paketen abhängt, während in der DG jedes Element höchstens ein Regens hat.

Comment: Die Substanzabhängigkeiten sind noch langweiliger: Dabei handelt es sich doch immer um eine Beziehung zwischen einer Person und (wieder möglicherweise mehreren) Substanzen, also Höhe 1. Da benötigt man das Instrumentarium der "diskreten Mathematik" nicht.

Comment: Auch wenn der grammatische Begriff eine 1-n-Beziehung zwischen Regens und Dependens fordert, scheint es mir dennoch sinnvoll, den Begriff außerhalb der Grammatik auf Situationen anzuwenden, in denen eine n-n-Beziehung vorliegt. Denn diese Beschränkung ist ja "nur" konventionell und nur im Bereich der Grammatik relevant; im Wortsinn liegt es nicht.

Answer (score 1):

Ein Hinweis darauf, dass es vielleicht kein Wort dafür im Deutschen gibt, ist die Tatsache, dass sich in der Informatik dafür - parallel zum englischen "dependency" - das Wort "Abhängigkeit" durchzusetzen beginnt, das ja eigentlich etwas anderes bedeutet.

> Der Paketmanager installiert das Paket und alle seine Abhängigkeiten.
> The package manager installs the package and any dependencies.

Mit dieser Formulierung ist gemeint, dass ein Softwarepaket installiert wird und außerdem Softwarepakete, die nötig sind, damit dieses Paket laufen kann.

Beispiel für diese Verwendung: https://www.ionos.de/digitalguide/websites/web-entwicklung/einfuehrung-in-nodejs/ Im Zusammenhang mit Softwarepaketen ist diese Verwendung inzwischen üblich, Google findet viele entsprechende Beispiele.

In der Mathematik und Physik wird für Abhängigkeitsrelationen zwischen Variablen auch einfach das Paar "abhängige Variable" - "unabhängige/freie Variable" benutzt. Solange man nicht ganze Ketten von Abhängigkeitsverhältnissen betrachtet, ist das vielleicht auch eine Alternative.

Je nach Kontext gibt es bessere Begriffe wie Voraussetzung, Bedingung, Erfordernis, Basis, Fundament, Erwartung oder ähnliches, aber einen allgemeinen Begriff scheint es mir nicht zu geben.

Comment: Deine Vorschläge haben mich auf Abhängigkeitsgrundlage gebracht.